# How to turn an x509.Certificate into a tls.Certificate in Go?

Tags: go, cryptography

I'm using [x/crypto/pkcs12](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12) to load a DER formatted *.p12 file. There is [an example in the documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12#example-ToPEM) that uses `tls.X509KeyPair` to make a `tls.Certificate` which can be used for an HTTP client.

That's perfect, and works fine. But then I also want to verify that the certificate hasn't expired. The `pkcs12` library also has a [Decode function](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12#Decode) which returns an x509 certificate, that I can than use the [Verify](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate.Verify) method on. This also works fine.

It just seems odd to me that I'm decoding the DER twice. Once for an `x509.Certificate` to verify, and again to get a `tls.Certificate`. I don't know the relationship between these two Certificate structures, but seeing as the tls package has a function named tls.X509KeyPair that takes some bytes, shouldn't there also be an obvious way to get a tls.Certificate from an x509.Certificate or visa versa? What am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A tls.Certificate often stores a certificate *chain* - in other words, > 1 certificate. Notice its `Certificate` field is of type `[][]byte`, where each certificate is a `[]byte`.

The tls package imports the x509 package, so there isn't a function in x509 to get a tls.Certificate; that would cause an import cycle. But if you have an x509.Certificate, you already have a tls.Certificate; just put the x509.Certificate's `Raw` bytes into a tls.Certificate's `Certificate` slice.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll give it a try. Do I need to do anything with the other fields of tls.Certificate or call any functions, or should it "just work"?

I noticed that x509.Certificate.Verify() also returns chains.

Comment: TLS servers will need the `PrivateKey` field set to successfully complete the handshake. I think the rest is optional.

Comment: Looks like I need a PrivateKey for clients to. Looking into it.

tls: client certificate private key of type <nil> does not implement crypto.Signer

Comment: It looks like there just isn't a good way to do what I want with the current Go crypto APIs. X509KeyPair uses an internal parsePrivateKey function with keyDERBlock bytes which I'm not sure how to get out of the X509. It also does a bunch of PublicKey validation. 

I'd rather not copy/paste all that out of standard library, so I'm reverting to decoding twice.

Comment: I gave up to soon. There is a response from Wim Lewis with Leaf and ParsedKey set. It appears to be working now (on Go tip at least) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/7l75mp2gh1o/ntF5DD-hCAAJ

Comment: also got this working with Wim's advice from the google group

Comment: Wim's  Code:  
    ```thing := tls.Certificate{ 
    Certificate: [][]byte{ parsedCert.Raw }, 
    PrivateKey: parsedPrivateKey, 
    Leaf: parsedCert, 
}```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
func LoadP12TLSCfg(keystore, password string) (*x509.CertPool, tls.Certificate, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(keystore)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, tls.Certificate{}, err

    }
    pk, crt, caCrts, err := pkcs12.DecodeChain(data, password)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, tls.Certificate{}, err
    }
    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pool.AddCert(caCrts[0])
    tlsCrt := tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{crt.Raw},
        Leaf:        crt,
        PrivateKey:  pk,
    }
    return pool, tlsCrt, nil
}

func LoadServerTLSCfg(keystore, password string) (*tls.Config, error) {
    pool, crt, err := LoadP12TLSCfg(keystore, password)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    cfg := &tls.Config{
        ClientCAs:    pool,
        ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{crt},
    }
    return cfg, nil
}

func LoadClientTLSCfg(keystore, password string, serverName string) (*tls.Config, error) {
    pool, crt, err := LoadP12TLSCfg(keystore, password)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    cfg := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:      pool,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{crt},
        ServerName:   serverName,
    }
    return cfg, nil
}
```